# Getting a list of tag counts for a specific Owner using acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a User that is the owner for a set of Posts. I want to get a set of tag *counts* for the Posts that the user has tagged, but the method doesn't seem to be available.

I'd like something like: @user.tag_counts_on(:context) akin to `@post.tag_counts(:context)`

For a standalone Post, I can use `@post.tag_counts_on(:thoughts)` to get a tag cloud for the context of "thoughts"

But the only available methods for an owner of taggings is: `@user.owned_taggings`, and `@userowned_tags`. Is there a way to access this?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't. I think this is going to require a custom query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `all_tag_counts` method [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/98aecdd86ddf447a88ae6351cc02ab420a78d0ec/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/collection.rb)? It's what `tag_counts_on` calls and it accepts a hash of options, where `conditions` is "A piece of SQL conditions to add to the query" so I think this may work, not completely sure though?

`@post.tag_counts_on(:context, { conditions: "posts.user_id IS #{@user.id}" })`